# Laravel migration migraine

Tags: mysql, laravel, vagrant, migrate, laravel-artisan

I created a laravel project using version 4.2.9 in my local computer. Then I used `vaprobash` to set-up my `vm`. My `Vagrantfile` provisioned `MySQL` , `php5.5`, `composer` and a composer package. I am using Mac OS X 10.9.4.

I was following `laracast` tutorial and run this command in my local computer

```
php artisan generate:migration create_users_table --fields="username:string, email:string:unique, password:string(20), remember_token:string"
```

This resulted into an error

```
{"error":{"type":"Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException","message":"syntax error, unexpected ''database'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ')'","file":"\/Users\/xxxmexxx\/lampfolder\/laraproj\/app\/config\/database.php","line":51}}
```

I realized that I should have run it on my `vm ssh` so I did. I `vagrant ssh` then run the same command and got the same error. Now, it seems like I can not run any artisan commands. I tried

```
php artisan -v
```

Same error.

and these are the code starting from line 51 of `database.php`

```
        'database' => __DIR__.'/../database/production.sqlite',
        'prefix'   => '',
    ),

    'mysql' => array(
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => 'localhost',
        'database'  => 'laraproj',
        'username'  => 'root',
        'password'  => 'root',
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
    ),
```

Line 51 should not even matter because I specified `'default' => 'mysql';` and lines 51 and 52 are parameters of `sqlite`.

I need advise on how to proceed.
Should I vagrant destroy? Should I provisioned laravel project in my `vm` as well? Should I delete my laravel instead? Or should I destroy my monitor instead? bec I am almost ready to do it.

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: What if you delete all database definitions and only leave the mysql one in? Are you sure you're not running in production mode and the wrong file is included?

Comment: Sure you are not missing a comma or something on line 50?

Comment: @hebron Whooaaatttt???? You got mad skills bro. I found the missing comma and is back where it belongs, and my monitor wants to say - thank you!

Comment: Glad it worked out. Mo you can not up-vote yet, but you can accept an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something is missing before line 51, so presumably a comma is missing or a semicolon is there where there shouldn't be one. Unexpected anything is always caused by something before the actual displayed line.

Comment: Thanks man, you and hebron nailed it! I tried to vote up but a guy, missing a comma, is not worthy of anything worthwhile such as voting up. I tried... anyways - thank you.

Comment: @aFreshMelon you were right! "Unexpected anything is always caused by something before the actual displayed line."